# Rails query syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I'm kinda new on the Rails boat, I would like to know the difference between two types of syntax for queries

The first one I tried is:

```
User.limit(8).order('created_at DESC').group('created_at').count
```

The second, which seems to be far more efficient and powerful:

```
User.count(:order =>'DATE(created_at) DESC', :group =>["DATE(created_at)"], :limit => 8)
```

But I don't really understand the use case for both.
I'm sure this is something obvious anyway... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is rails 3 syntax. And each method used there, i.e, `limit, order, group` are `ActiveRecord:: Relation` method. There are various advantages in using the 1st method. ActiveRecord::Relation is one of the core features of rails 3 apart from asset pipeline etc.

Please read this,

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough

Comment: The most interesting feature of the new syntax is that you can build your query step by step, like `@users = @users.where(somecondition) if params[:blah].present?`. And that you can use them in defining scopes too: `scope :cuckoo { where(blah).order("field") }`

Answer (score 0):

Well the second syntax is the deprecated, old-school, syntax. Also known as Hash-Options-Overload. The first, chaining, syntax is the way forward.

Comment: So I should only use the first one ? Everywhere ?

Comment: Also, the deprecated one have an handy method, here in my example I want to group the item by day but the field created_at also have the time. the DATE thing handle it for me. How should I reproduce it in the other example ? Currently it group by the full DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the powerful and efficient. Because first one will take all the rows (and all the columns) and then it will count. But the second one will perform only counting the rows.

Second one will use the following query.

select count(*) from tablename;

Comment: Wrong, the second one does exactly the same as the first. The one that takes all the rows in memory and then counts them is `User.find(...).length`, which converts the query to an array and then calculates the length of the array.